# UILabel autolayout with autoshrink text height works fine, but horizontal width doesn't match

Tags: ios, autolayout

In Interface Builder I set up a UITableViewCell xib with a bunch of UILabels. Then, according to accepted practice, for each text or UILabelField I set:

```
'number of lines' = 0, 
'autoshrink' = 'minimum font size',
'minimum font size' = something small (e.g.9), 
'font size' = something huge (e.g. 90),
constrain the height to a proportion of the superview height, 
set the 'clip subviews' to true, 
and 'Line Break' to 'word wrap'.
```

The vertical heights adjust exactly as I expect. However the width of the fields match the intrinsic content size provided by the big font, regardless of how I set the horizontal content hugging priority.

You might wonder why this matters if the text is rendered exactly as desired.

I also use a horizontal spacing constraint to position elements to the right of these text or label views. The constraints see the horizontal intrinsic content size of the elements on the left, and so they push the trailing elements all the way to the right (off the edge of the view).

How can I get the horizontal width of the (label, text, etc) views to follow the text width based on the autoshrink value of the font size?

I imagine adjusting the widths in the viewDidAppear method of the view controller would work, but I'm resisting this because I stubbornly believe that this should be possible in interface builder, without coding.

Comment: You could try constraining the aspect ratio

Comment: In fact that sort of works, but given the limitations of interface builder in generating constraints, I think you'd have to calculate the ratio of width to height as a constant. Unfortunately it's not exactly linear for the same string at different sizes. Because of the way type scales, the width at various font sizes can wander quite a ways from linear. To make it exact, I would have to ask iOS for the intrinsic content size of the string at a particular size, and set the aspect ratio to be the ratio of height to width. I could do that in code, but not a constraint in interface builder.

Comment: Also, the aspect ratio would be different for every string that might appear in the label, which is something that Isn't always determined at the time the constraint is being added in interface builder.